# what value to give in the yammer app redirect uri

Tags: yammer

what value to give in the yammer app redirect uri if I want this app to be used by multiple different sites having multiple different domains.

I mean, I have two different sites abc.com and cde.com which will use the same app. So, what should be given in the redirect URI of the app.

Answer (score 0):

There are no strict rules for the redirect URI value, but you MUST ensure that the URL is valid and accessible from your user's locations. See [here](https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/app-registration) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a single app for multiple websites. If you have two websites, you have to create two apps and you can change the app-code and redirect url at the run time accordingly.